# Get select values from different textareas and insert into a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently learning JS and working on creating a HTML invoice. I want to take values from three textareas that are entered and then add them to the end of my table (The total is calculated automatically whose function is working fine). Currently I've added blank fields using

```
$("#addrow").click(function(){
    $(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea>Item Name</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td><textarea class="cost">0</textarea></td><td><textarea class="qty">0</textarea></td><td><span class="price">0</span></td></tr>');
```

But I do not know how to get the three values I enter getting added to the table when I click on add

[Image of table with empty fields added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATBUv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the value from the inputs and then concatenate them in your append.

Try this:

```
$("#addrow").click(function(){
var itemName = $('#add-description').val();
var itemHours = $('#add-hours').val();
var itemRate = $('#add-rate').val();

$(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea id="new-description">'+itemName+'</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td><textarea class="cost">'+itemHours+'</textarea></td><td><textarea class="qty">'+itemRate+'</textarea></td><td><span class="price">0</span></td></tr>');
if ($(".delete").length > 0) $(".delete").show();
bind();});
```

Example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVPbrX?editors=1010)

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! That works but in the second row the first column data is changing every time you change the content in the new item div

Comment: That is due to another function you have in your code, try the CodePen again.

Comment: Thank you! This did the job!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get the text from text area. Get all three text from text boxes and append into the td of the table

Text area :

```
var bla = $('textarea:input[name=txt_area]').val();
```

Text Box :

```
var bla = $('#txt_name').val();
```

Comment: Sorry not sure how to use that. I currently have a messy function where I add new rows but the same id gets applied to every new row with only one row working. codepen.io/anon/pen/wyYYZL?editors=1010 This is my current work so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for your requirement

```
**var taskdescription = document.getElementById('taskdescription').value;
var hours = document.getElementById('hours').value;
var rate = document.getElementById('rate').value;
var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;



var table = document.getElementById('table');
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td = document.createElement("td");
var txt = document.createTextNode(taskdescription);
    td.appendChild(txt);

var td1 = document.createElement("td");
var txt1 = document.createTextNode(hours);
    td1.appendChild(txt1);

var td2 = document.createElement("td");
var txt2 = document.createTextNode(rate);
    td2.appendChild(txt2);

var td3 = document.createElement("td");
var txt3 = document.createTextNode(amount);
    td3.appendChild(txt3);

tr.appendChild(td);
tr.appendChild(td1);
tr.appendChild(td2);
tr.appendChild(td3);

table.appendChild(tr);**
```

this will automaticlly append your data into table

Comment: Sorry not sure how to use that. I currently have a messy function where I add new rows but the same id gets applied to every new row with only one row working.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyYYZL?editors=1010

This is my current work so far